# Is chunking.success.endpoint supposed to be called even when there is only a single chunk?

Tags: fine-uploader

If I have chunking enabled and a success endpoint defined:

```
chunking: {
    enabled: true,
    concurrent: {
        enabled: true
    },
    success: {
        endpoint: "/FileUploadComplete"
    }
},
```

The endpoint "/FileUploadComplete" is not hit unless the file is larger than the chunk size. Documentation (http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/concurrent-chunking.html) states that "Fine Uploader will send a POST after all chunks have been successfully uploaded for each file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. If the file is not chunked, none of the chunking-related logic/options/endpoints apply.

Comment: Could you maybe point me in the direction of how to do post-processing? My understanding going into it was that the chunking success endpoint would be where I combine/rename/move the file (whatever it is I want to do for post-processing). I don't know where else I'd do this, and I need to do post-processing on all file uploads, not just uploads that were delivered in multiple chunks.

Comment: The `chunking.success.endpoint` is called to allow your server to combine all parts. It isn't meant for general post-processing beyond this. You can send a request to your server when your [`onComplete` handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete) is called to perform more general post-processing.

Comment: Thank you very much Ray!